# Suppose $n \in \Bbb N$ has a root that isn't whole, prove $\sqrt n$ is irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers

Suppose $n \in \Bbb N$ has a square root that isn't whole, prove $\sqrt n$ is irrational.
The exercise wants me to prove it in the following steps:
Suppose $\sqrt n$ is rational, then there exists a minimal natural number $p$ such that $p \sqrt n$ is a natural number. Now, observe the number $q=p \sqrt n -p \lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor$.

I'm not really sure what I can infer from $q$, I tried squaring $q$ but I couldn't infer anything either.

Comment: Try looking at q for some example values of p and n.

Comment: I guess I need to prove that $q=0$ and then reach a contradiction, but I'm not really sure how to go about it, I'm not well-oriented in the floor function.

Comment: You've assumed $p$ is minimal. If you can show that $q$ is even smaller, but has all the other properties of $p$....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$q<p$, and $q\sqrt{n}\in \mathbb{N}$, but $p$ was the minimal, so you get a contradiction

Comment: You also need to point out that $q>0$ (otherwise, you have proved $\sqrt n$ is irrational for all $n$, even the ones that are squares), and you need to note that $q$ is a positive integer.